# how to reach tabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i have a navigation application with a tab bar and there is a web view in first view which is related with first tab bar item . with a button web view appears and i want to hide it when i touch the first tab bar item .. Please help thx

Answer (score 2):

To get the controller, just:

```
[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:indexOfTheTab]
```

`tabBarController` refers to `UITabBarController *tabBarController` in you AppDelegate.

EDIT 1: add this to your AppDelegate.h

```
-(UITabBarController*)getTabBarController;
```

add this to your AppDelegate.m

```
-(UITabBarController*)getTabBarController { return tabBarController; }
```

Now, you can access it from everywhere:

```
[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] getTabBarController]
```

Don't forget `#import "AppDelegate.h"`

EDIT 2: In you AppDelegate.m

In the first method, just add: `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Then, override:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //something like : [tabBarController hideTheStuffs];
}
```

With EDIT 2 you can listen to the user touches in the tab bar, even if the tab item is already the current one. With EDIT 1 you can access your delegate from everywhere if needed.

EDIT 3:

Do you have a `IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView` in you ControllerView.h (the one with the view that shows the web view).
If not, add this outlet, then connect it to your webview in interface builder.

In the controller, add a method in .h and .m :

`-(void)hideTheWebView { myWebView.hidden = YES; }`

As this method is declared in the interface (.h), you can call it from the AppDelegate, method tabBarController:didSelectViewController.

Comment: i have a controller in my appdelegate ... but i just want to reach the first tab bar button from another class than app delegate ... Do yopu knoew how to do .. can you show me complete code pls ?

Comment: Done. That's how I do in my projects.

Comment: thx i did all the things but still i don't know where and how to use [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] getTabBarController] i want if anyone presses to the tab bar button web is going to be hidden ( sorry i'm new to these things )

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood your goal.

Have a look at my second EDIT of the answer :)

Comment: i did the second edit and copied the  self.tabBarController.delegate = self; to my app delegate ... and i copied  - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
 if (tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0)
 {
  img.hidden;  
 }
} to my view controllers method which is FirstTabNavController.m but nothing changed .. what is the wrong ?

Comment: Nope... the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController...` has to be in the AppDelegate.m, not in your controller. Then you can call from this method your controller to hide img.

Comment: i don't know how to call can you help ?

Comment: i did this but i am saying i don't know how to call but you say call from AppDelegate :)

Comment: Just do the EDIT 2 in your AppDelegate.h/.m (the correct name should me MyProjectNameAppDelegate.h/.m). It's just 1 little method :)